# PostgreSQL - query all tables' all table columns

Tags: python, sql, arrays, database, postgresql

How can I query all tables' all table columns in a database?

Method I've tried:

1. get all table names using `select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public'`
2. Process cmd string using `UNION` method of Postgres.
3. Execute the cmd string.

I have 19 tables in a DB, and my method results in 19 times slower querying time. And further more, it does not return what I want. All of the tables have two columns, one of them always being a column name called `time`. Using the `UNION` method does not return 19 `time` strings. It just returns one `time` string, and 19 other column names. But I want something like this:
`[('table_1', ['time', 'col']), ('table_2', ['time', 'col']), ('table_3', ['time', 'col])...]`.

Is there any elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this in a single query by using `array_agg()` and a join on the `information_schema.tables` and `information_schema.columns` tables.

This would return something similar to your expected output:

```
select
    t.table_name,
    array_agg(c.column_name::text) as columns
from
    information_schema.tables t
inner join information_schema.columns c on
    t.table_name = c.table_name
where
    t.table_schema = 'public'
    and t.table_type= 'BASE TABLE'
    and c.table_schema = 'public'
group by t.table_name;
```

Here I'm taking all the tables first, then I join it with the columns tables, and finally use `array_agg()` to aggregate them all to an array, grouped by the table name.

Hope it helps :) Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're working in Python, clearest if you handle this in two steps I think. First, use this query to retrieve table/column name pairs:

```
select table_name, column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name in (
    select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public');
```

Then, stick the results into a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_cols = <your code to execute the query above and fetch all rows>
column_mapping = defaultdict(list)
for tablename, colname in my_cols:
    column_mapping[tablename].append(colname)
```

This will give you:

```
>>> column_mapping
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'table_1': ['time', 'col'], 'table_2': ['time', 'col'], 'table_3': ['time', 'col]})
```

Which you can convert trivially with:

```
>>> column_mapping.items()
[('table_1', ['time', 'col']), ('table_2', ['time', 'col']), ('table_3', ['time', 'col])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a VIEW like this

```
CREATE VIEW table_column_info AS

SELECT table_name, STRING_AGG(column_name, ', ') AS columns
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
GROUP BY table_name;
```

And use it at your own disposal: `SELECT * FROM table_column_info;`

Answer (score 0):

It is a **query for all tables** in specified schemas.

```sql
SELECT 
    pg_namespace.nspname as schema_name,
    relname as table_name,
    pg_catalog.obj_description(pg_class.oid) as comment
    FROM pg_class
    INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
    WHERE pg_namespace.nspname IN ('public') AND pg_class.relkind IN ('r', 't')
    ORDER BY relname
```

The example filters only `public` schema, but you can specify your own.
Condition `relkind IN ('r', 't')` describes that we need only tables, without indexes, sequences and other.
Here is a doc for table pg_class - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html
Function `pg_catalog.obj_description` returns a comment for the database object.
Here is a doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE

It is as **query for all columns** in specified tables:

```sql
SELECT 
    attrelid::regclass AS table_name,
    attname            AS column_name, 
    pg_catalog.col_description(attrelid, attnum) as column_comment,
    atttypid::regtype  AS column_datatype
    FROM pg_attribute
    INNER JOIN pg_class ON pg_class.oid = attrelid
    WHERE attrelid IN (
        SELECT pg_class.oid
        FROM pg_class
        INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
        WHERE pg_namespace.nspname IN ('public') AND pg_class.relkind IN ('r', 't')
    )
    AND attnum > 0 AND attisdropped IS FALSE
    ORDER BY pg_class.relname, pg_attribute.attnum
```

Condition `attnum > 0 AND attisdropped IS FALSE` describes that we need only visible and not deleted columns.
Here is a doc for table pg_attribute - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html
Function `pg_catalog.col_description` returns a comment for the table column.